# How to pass an array as args to Nexus? How to create multiple objects from this array using Prisma?

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma2, nexus-js

I'm trying to learn to use Prisma and Nexus together. I'm hoping that someone more experienced can help me out.

I want to create a post with several images attached to it.

My Prisma models look like this:

```
model Post {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  title String
  body String
  images Image[] @relation("ImagePost")
}

model Image {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  post Post @relation("ImagePost", fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId String
  name String
  url String
}
```

I need to write a Nexus mutation that can accept a post with a title, body, and array of image urls. I need to create an Image record for each of the urls, and attach them to the post.

```
const Mutation = objectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  definition(t) {
    t.field('createPost', {
      type: 'Post',
      args: {
        title: nonNull(stringArg()),
        body: stringArg(),
        images: ????
      },
      resolve: (_, args, context: Context) => {
        return context.prisma.post.create({
          data: {
            title: args.title,
            body: args.body,
            images: ????
          },
        })
      },
    })
})
```

Can you help me to figure out how to do this correctly?

1. I don't know how to pass an array of json objects to the args. There are things like `stringArg()` or `intArg()`, but how do you accept an array?
2. What's the right way to create a bunch of `Image` objects and attach them to the `Post`? Should I have a for loop and create them manually one by one, and then attach them somehow? Or is there a better way?

Do you know if there are any examples of people doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Just like `nonNull` there's also a `list` type. You can use that and create an `arg` in that.

As for creating images, you can use `create` and pass the array of images to `post` as shown [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference/#create-a-new-user-record-with-two-new-post-records).

Answer (score 1):

I have done that using the `extendInputType`, here you go an example

1. First you have to define de input

```
export const saleDetailInput = extendInputType({
  type: 'SaleDetailInput',
  definition(t) {
    t.field(SaleDetail.productId)
  }
});
```

2. Define the args

```
export const createSale = extendType({
  type: 'Mutation',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.list.field('createSale', {
      type: 'Sale',
      args: {
        total: nonNull(floatArg()),
        customerId: nonNull(intArg()),
        products: nonNull(list(nonNull('SaleDetailInput'))),
      },
      async resolve(parent, { products, ...others }, context) {
      },
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a more detailed example from [nexus](https://nexusjs.org/docs/api/list-nonNull#list). no need to create a new `inputObjectType`. It's just simple as the below `arg` example.

```js
import { queryType, stringArg, list } from 'nexus'
queryType({
  definition(t) {
    t.field('tags', {
      type: list('String'), // -> [String]
      args: {
        ids: list(stringArg()) // or list('String') -> [String]
      },
      resolve() {
        // ...
      }
    })
  }
})
```